# How to linking .so file with cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am try to linking to .so file libbasic.so (I generate him) and this lib are include two functions add and sub.
I want to check this functions with google test but I got this error:

```
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ExampleTests.dir/ExampleTests.cpp.o: in function `basic_add_Test::TestBody()':
[build] /home/eylon/Example/test/ExampleTests.cpp:38: undefined reference to `sub(int, int)'
[build] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8) 

set(This Example) 

project(${This})
project(${This} C CXX) 

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)


enable_testing() 

add_subdirectory(googletest)
add_subdirectory(test)

set(Headers
    Example.hpp
)
set(Sources
    Example.cpp
)


add_library(${This} STATIC ${Sources} ${Headers})


link_directories(home/eylon/)

target_link_libraries(Example libbasic.so)
```

This is the test CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
set(This ExampleTests)

set(Sources
../basic.h
ExampleTests.cpp
)

add_executable(${This} ${Sources})

target_link_libraries(${This} PUBLIC
gtest_main
gmock_main
Example
)



add_test(
NAME ${This}
COMMAND ${This}
)
```

The .so file inludes this:
add.c

```
int add(int a, int b){
return a + b;}
```

sub.c

```
int sub(int a, int b)
 {
 return a - b;
 }
```

basic.h

```
   int add(int a, int b);
   int sub(int a, int b);
```

i generate the .so file with this commands:

```
gcc -fPIC -c add.c
gcc -fPIC -c sub.c
gcc -shared -o libbasic.so add.o sub.o
```

Comment: `I generate him` how do you generate it? with cmake?

Comment: Without any further information, it is hard to tell what you did wrong. It could be that you make a mistake when creating your `libbasic.so` (like forgetting to add the file that contains the definition of `sub(int, int)` into your build, or your `sub(…)` function is a template and you included its definition in the source instead of the header, …)

Comment: `i generate the .so file with this commands:` why don't you generate it in `cmake` with `add_library(... SHARED)`? Try `link_directories(./)` with\ `target_link_libraries(Example basic)`.